# Tabular Model Measures Not Populating

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssas, sql-server-data-tools, ssas-tabular

[Measures Grid Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X1PB.png)

So I'm working in a Tabular Model Solution using SSDT/Visual Studio-15.  None of my measures or calculated columns have any errors.  I'm having a very difficult time working in the model because my measures in the measures grid don't always populate.  They just show me the name of the field and not the actual value.  I have tried doing a restart, reconnecting the model to SSMS and every little trick that I was able to find online.  Why don't my measures populate 100% of the time?  I have other models that were built before I started this job and they populate more than the subject model but still less than 100% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tabular model that you're using in SSDT in the workspace database, which is essentially an in-memory copy of the model that you use in development, as opposed to where you're deploying the changes to.  You've probably noticed it in SSMS, as its name is the model name plus your username and a GUID.  Where and how it's stored will depend on if a workspace server or integrated workspace is used, and the configurations from there.  To populate the measures and calculated columns in SSDT, process the cube from within SSDT.

Comment: Thanks for the note @userfl89.  My issue isn't that they don't populate at all.  My issue is that my measures aren't consistently displaying values.  At the time of this original question, what you saw in the attached image is what my SSDT was displaying.  Currently, this very second I can see values for every measure in every tab.  Nothing has changed in regard to my connection or the data.  My question is why do the measure not consistently show values [all the time]?